# FanDuel NBA Lineup Optimizer

Tags: python-3.x

This code runs without error and for the life of me I can't put my finger on why it doesn't return any output besides a "Usage: " message followed by the path to the CSV file it should be reading/parsing.

Any help is appreciated.

```
salary_cap = 60000


def get_position_number(name):
    return {
        'Center': 0,
        'Point Guard': 1,
        'Power Forward': 2,
        'Shooting Guard': 3,
        'Small Forward': 4
    }[name]


def main(a, y):
    solver = pywraplp.Solver('CoinsGridCLP',
    pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIaED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

range_c = range(len(a[0]))
range_pg = range(len(a[1]))
range_pf = range(len(a[2]))
range_sg = range(len(a[3]))
range_sf = range(len(a[4]))

take_c = [solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'take_c[%i]' % j) for j in range_c]
take_pg = [solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'take_pg[%i]' % j) for j in range_pg]
take_pf = [solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'take_pf[%i]' % j) for j in range_pf]
take_sg = [solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'take_sg[%i]' % j) for j in range_sg]
take_sf = [solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'take_sf[%i]' % j) for j in range_sf]

teams_c = []
teams_pg = []
teams_pf = []
teams_sg = []
teams_sf = []

for teamNumber in range(0, 29):
    teams_c.insert(teamNumber, solver.Sum([(a[0][i][3] == teamNumber + 1) * take_c[i] for i in range_c]))
    teams_pg.insert(teamNumber, solver.Sum([(a[1][i][3] == teamNumber + 1) * take_pg[i] for i in range_pg]))
    teams_pf.insert(teamNumber, solver.Sum([(a[2][i][3] == teamNumber + 1) * take_pf[i] for i in range_pf]))
    teams_sg.insert(teamNumber, solver.Sum([(a[3][i][3] == teamNumber + 1) * take_sg[i] for i in range_sg]))
    teams_sf.insert(teamNumber, solver.Sum([(a[4][i][3] == teamNumber + 1) * take_sf[i] for i in range_sf]))

value_c = solver.Sum([a[0][i][1] * take_c[i] for i in range_c])
value_pg = solver.Sum([a[1][i][1] * take_pg[i] for i in range_pg])
value_pf = solver.Sum([a[2][i][1] * take_pf[i] for i in range_pf])
value_sg = solver.Sum([a[3][i][1] * take_sg[i] for i in range_sg])
value_sf = solver.Sum([a[4][i][1] * take_sf[i] for i in range_sf])

salray_c = solver.Sum([a[0][i][2] * take_c[i] for i in range_c])
salray_pg = solver.Sum([a[1][i][2] * take_pg[i] for i in range_pg])
salray_pf = solver.Sum([a[2][i][2] * take_pf[i] for i in range_pf])
salray_sg = solver.Sum([a[3][i][2] * take_sg[i] for i in range_sg])
salray_sf = solver.Sum([a[4][i][2] * take_sf[i] for i in range_sf])

solver.Add(salray_c + salray_pg + salray_pf + salray_sg + salray_sf <= y)

solver.Add(solver.Sum(take_c[i] for i in range_c) == 1)
solver.Add(solver.Sum(take_pg[i] for i in range_pg) == 2)
solver.Add(solver.Sum(take_pf[i] for i in range_pf) == 2)
solver.Add(solver.Sum(take_sg[i] for i in range_sg) == 2)
solver.Add(solver.Sum(take_sf[i] for i in range_sf) == 2)

# Maa 4 a per team
for i in range(0, 29):
    solver.Add(teams_c[i] + teams_pg[i] + teams_pf[i] + teams_sg[i] + teams_sf[i] <= 4)

solver.Maaimize(value_c + value_pg + value_pf + value_sg + value_sf)
solver.Solve()
assert solver.VerifySolution(1e-7, True)
print('Solved in', solver.wall_time(), 'milliseconds!', "\n")
salary = 0

for i in range_c:
    if take_c[i].SolutionValue():
        salary += a[0][i][2]
        print(a[0][i][0], '(C): ${:,d}'.format(a[0][i][2]), '(' + str(a[0][i][1]) + ')')

for i in range_pg:
    if take_pg[i].SolutionValue():
        salary += a[1][i][2]
        print(a[1][i][0], '(PG): ${:,d}'.format(a[1][i][2]), '(' + str(a[1][i][1]) + ')')

for i in range_pf:
    if take_pf[i].SolutionValue():
        salary += a[2][i][2]
        print(a[2][i][0], '(PF): ${:,d}'.format(a[2][i][2]), '(' + str(a[2][i][1]) + ')')

for i in range_sg:
    if take_sg[i].SolutionValue():
        salary += a[3][i][2]
        print(a[3][i][0], '(SG): ${:,d}'.format(a[3][i][2]), '(' + str(a[3][i][1]) + ')')

for i in range_sf:
    if take_sf[i].SolutionValue():
        salary += a[4][i][2]
        print(a[4][i][0], '(SF): ${:,d}'.format(a[4][i][2]), '(' + str(a[4][i][1]) + ')')

print("\n", 'Total: ${:,d}'.format(salary), '(' + str(solver.Objective().Value()) + ')')


if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage:', sys.executable, sys.argv[0], 'players.csv')
    sys.exit(1)

team = [[], [], [], [], []]


with open('players.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

for row in reader:
    team[get_position_number(row['Subposition'])].append(
        [row['Name'], float(row['Value']), int(row['Salary']), int(row['Team'])]
    )


main(team, salary_cap)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking questions on SO, please try to reduce your problem to a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most of the time the error will become evident while doing this. If that is not possible, please tell us what you want to achieve (what you expect to happen) as well as what actually happened. This makes your question easier to answer.

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What is happening

The following bit of code

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage:', sys.executable, sys.argv[0], 'players.csv')
    sys.exit(1)
```

checks if the argument vector, a list that contains the name of your script and all parameters given to it via command line, is shorter than two.
As an example, take the following file:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv, len(sys.argv))
```

If you run:

```
$ python your_script.py
$ ['your_script.py'] 1
$ python your_script.py parameter
$ ['your_script.py', 'parameter'] 2
```

In the first example the argument vector has length one, in the second it has length two.

Back to your script. If the argument vector has less then two entries, i.e. no parameters were given by the user, the program terminates with error code 1 (`sys.exit(1)`, every value != 1 indicates an error).

### How to fix it

You need to give your script a .csv file as first command line parameter:

```
$ python your_script players.csv
```

Otherwise the script has nothing to work with. Dave Hensley also mentions this in the [README of this script](https://github.com/davehensley/fanduel-nba-optimizer) in the section Usage.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for talking me through it. I think Dave's README could be more clear. I'm working through a fork of his repo to see if it could be improved. Either way, thanks for the guidance.